# Cheap accommodation in Fichtelgebirge?

Tags: budget, germany, accommodation, mountains, bavaria

Are there any cheap/economic class accommodations available in Fichtelgebirge (in German part)?

I've searched for mountain huts there, but I haven't found anything. Is it possible to overnight there for single person for the price comparable to mountain huts or hostels -something around 10-15€? I've found only hotels and inns, but they are very expensive if you are alone - from what I know renting a bed in multi-bed room instead of single room isn't a common practice in such places.

Answer (score 4):

The cheapest one I could find was [Bullhead House](http://www.bullheadhouse.de/house-pension.php) in Warmensteinach with prices starting from 16 EUR per night.

Comment: But for single person it's 24€ :(

Comment: you can book a single bed in 3- or 4-bed-room

Comment: Like in hostel? Nice option to consider.